# Reading two .dat files for calculating location distance

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm creating a program that reads data from two .dat files: one for food-bank location and the other for residence.  Right now, the program can calculate the distance between food-bank and residence and insert it into a distances vector.

My concerns are:

1. Is my logic right?
2. Can I determine the distance, in miles, between each location in residences and the closest food bank in `foodbanks`?  Note: the function will calculate in meters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include<iterator>

using namespace std;

struct Foodbank
{
    double x;
    double y;


    //input stream overload
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, Foodbank &f) {
        return is>>f.x>>f.y;
    }
    //output stream overload
        friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Foodbank const &f) {
            return os << f.x  << "\t"<< f.y<<"\t";

        }
};
struct Residence
{
    double x;
    double y;
    //input stream overload
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, Residence &r) {
        return is>>r.x>>r.y;
    }
    //output stream overload
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Foodbank const &r) {
        return os << r.x  << "\t"<< r.y<<"\t";

    }
};

double distanceCalculate(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2);
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{




    ifstream foodbankFile("foodbanks.dat");
    ifstream residenceFile("residences.dat");

    //vectors data
    vector<Foodbank> foodbankData;
    vector<Residence> residenceData;
    vector<double> distances;


    copy(std::istream_iterator<Foodbank>(foodbankFile),
         std::istream_iterator<Foodbank>(),
         std::back_inserter<std::vector<Foodbank>>(foodbankData));
      std::cout<<"read "<<foodbankData.size()<<" data: "<<std::endl;


    copy(std::istream_iterator<Residence>(residenceFile),
         std::istream_iterator<Residence>(),
         std::back_inserter<std::vector<Residence>>(residenceData));

    std::cout<<"read "<<residenceData.size()<<" data: "<<std::endl;
    for(auto r:residenceData)
    {
        for(auto f:foodbankData)
        {
            //std::cout<<f.x <<", "<<f.y <<", "<<std::endl;
            distances.push_back(distanceCalculate(f.x,f.y,r.x,r.y));
        }
        //std::cout<<r.x <<", "<<r.y <<", "<<std::endl;
    }

     std::cout<<"read "<<distances.size()<<" data: "<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}


// the distance in metres
double distanceCalculate(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
{
    double x = x1 - x2;
    double y = y1 - y2;
    double dist;

    dist = pow(x,2)+pow(y,2);           //calculating distance by euclidean formula
    dist = sqrt(dist);                  //sqrt is function in math.h

    return dist;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stop doing this:

```
using namespace std;
```

Yes every text book does this. But once you start writing programs more than 10 lines long it causes issues. Prefix items in the standard namespace with `std::` (it was designed to be short). See detailed explanation here: [Why is using namespace std considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/14065)

OK. What is the difference between `Foodbank` and `Residence` looks like they should simply be a `Location` class. If in later code you you add differences you can derive from the `Location` (or better use a location member (prefer composition over inheritance)).

Be consistent (and neat with your spacing).

```
return os << r.x  << "\t"<< r.y<<"\t";
//                     ^^^      ^^^      Hard to read

return os << r.x  << "\t" << r.y << "\t";
```

When initializing your arrays. No need to use std::copy. Just use the iterators in the vectors constructor.

```
vector<Foodbank> foodbankData;
copy(std::istream_iterator<Foodbank>(foodbankFile),
     std::istream_iterator<Foodbank>(),
     std::back_inserter<std::vector<Foodbank>>(foodbankData));


// Can be replaced by a single line:
vector<Foodbank> foodbankData(std::istream_iterator<Foodbank>(foodbankFile),
                              std::istream_iterator<Foodbank>());
```

Not sure why you are pushing the distance into a long single array. That does not help you work stuff out.

```
for(auto r:residenceData)
{
    for(auto f:foodbankData)
    {
        //std::cout<<f.x <<", "<<f.y <<", "<<std::endl;
        distances.push_back(distanceCalculate(f.x,f.y,r.x,r.y));
    }
}
```

I would suspect that what you want is a 2D array. The `FoodBanks` on the Y axis and the `Residences` on the X axis (as an example). Then given any `Residences`  you just need to scan the array vertically to find the closest `FoodBank`.

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>>   distance;
for(auto r:residenceData)
{
    distance.push_back(std::vector<double>());

    for(auto f:foodbankData)
    {
        //std::cout<<f.x <<", "<<f.y <<", "<<std::endl;
        distances.back().push_back(distanceCalculate(f.x,f.y,r.x,r.y));
    }
}
```

Wow thats a lot of parameters

```
double distanceCalculate(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
```

If your `FoodBank` and `Residence` just inherited from a base of `Location` (or had a location member) then you can pass location as the start and end point and calculate the distance between them.